# How to clone a local repository using PyCharm

Tags: mercurial, pycharm

I'm currently using PyCharm but finding impossible to checkout or clone from a local Mercurial repository.

In the `Clone Mercurial Repository` dialog, you can put an URL to clone from, and works ok with HTTP URLs, but I'm clueless about how to do it from a local repository.

I've tried putting `file://` before the absolute path, but PyCharm keeps telling me no repository found there, so I have to open the console, clone, setup project, etc.

There must be a way, every other IDE I've used allows to do it

Thanks and regards!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works for me: [image: Mercurial checkout dialog]

It doesn't need "file://", just type in the path.
Are you on Windows or Linux/Mac?

Maybe, you use the "tilda" sign (~) for the home directory? This dialog doesn't understand tildas.

Also note, that you have to specify the path to the Mercurial root, not to the ".hg" directory itself.

Please share your path so that we could see, what can be treated incorrectly there.

Comment: Yes, you were right, seems like the tilde (Mac OSX) was not being expanded to $HOME. Thanks for the solution